# Implementing a class to represent cards, python property setter not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I want each card to have a suit and a face, and when I create a new card, the face and suit should only belong to the values listed in the fields `FACES`, `SUITS`. Otherwise I want to raise an exception. This is what I've written, but it is not raising the exceptions when I try to create an illegal card

```
class Card(object):

FACES = 'A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K'
SUITS = 'H', 'S', 'D', 'C'

def __init__(self, face, suit):
    self._face = face
    self._suit = suit

@property
def face(self):
    return self._face

@face.setter
def face(self, f):
    if f in self.FACES:
        self._face = f
    else:
        raise Exception('invalid face')

@property
def suit(self):
    return self._suit

@suit.setter
def suit(self, s):
    if s in self.SUITS:
        self._suit = s
    else:
        raise Exception('invalid suit')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is you're trying to **create** a card with invalid values, rather than creating a card with valid values, and then later trying to set them to something invalid. Right now your `__init__` method is bypassing your `property` objects (`face`/`suit`), and sets the private backing attributes (`_face`/`_suit`) directly. If you want `__init__` to go through the `property` attributes, you have to do this:

```
class Card(object):

    FACES = 'A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K'
    SUITS = 'H', 'S', 'D', 'C'

    def __init__(self, face, suit):
        # Initialize the private attributes to None
        self._face = None
        self._suit = None
        # Try to set what the user supplied to the public property attributes
        self.face = face
        self.suite = suit

    @property
    def face(self):
        return self._face

    @face.setter
    def face(self, f):
        if f in self.FACES:
            self._face = f
        else:
            raise Exception('invalid face')

    @property
    def suit(self):
        return self._suit

    @suit.setter
    def suit(self, s):
        if s in self.SUITS:
            self._suit = s
        else:
            raise Exception('invalid suit')
```

Now, I'm not sure if this is really how you want your API to work, since it probably doesn't make sense for someone to change the face/suit of a card once it's created. You may actually want something like this:

```
class Card(object):

    FACES = 'A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K'
    SUITS = 'H', 'S', 'D', 'C'

    def __init__(self, face, suit):
        # Initialize the private attributes to None
        if face not in self.FACES:
            raise Exception('invalid face')
        if suite not in self.SUIT:
            raise Exception("invalid suit")
        self._face = face
        self._suit = suit

    @property
    def face(self):
        return self._face

    @property
    def suit(self):
        return self._suit
```

That way `card.face` and `card.suit` are read-only attributes.

Comment: Thank you. Just took a course in Java programming and I am trying to get a handle on this @property business. Also, your suggestion on making it read only is very good. Thanks!